# Javascript - throw not working in an error handling situation

Tags: javascript, error-handling, try-catch, throw

I've been trying to define a function which checks whether a number is positive or not and I wanted to use "throw" but I didn't find a way to make it work using "throw". I trying using "throw" inside the "try" block as well but it didn't work either. So my question is...

Why does this work:

```
    function isPositive(a) {


    if (a < 0) {
        return 'Negative Number';
    }

    if (a == 0) {
        return 'Codename Error Zero'
    }

    try {
        return 'It IS a positive number!';
    }
    catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

and this doesn't:

```
    function isPositive(a) {


    if (a < 0) {
        throw 'Negative Number';
    }

    if (a == 0) {
        throw 'Codename Error Zero'
    }

    try {
        return 'It IS a positive number!';
    }
    catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: May you also share the code which runs these two functions? What doesn’t work?

Comment: in the second code example, code that calls the `isPositive` function should handle the error thrown from this function and in both code example, `try-catch` block is unnecessary. You probably want to wrap the `throw` statements in a `try` block

Comment: You should try putting your if() tests **within** the try block

Comment: Your try is in the wrong place, put at the start of your function.

Comment: @ATD that's exactly what I did at first and it's not working for some reason which is why I'm confused. It doesn't return anything for positive numbers. It just works for error cases (0 and neg).

Comment: @NiHaoLiHai  You have one `return` statement and two `throw` statements which output to the console.  The `return` statement will work if you call the function like `let x = isPositive(2);` - thus, `x` will show `It IS a positive number!`.  However, you also have to handle the results of the errors as well - otherwise nothing is returned (only output to the console).

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurs due to how `try .. catch` works. Try catch will first, try to do what is inside the bracket (which is to return the `It IS a positive number!`), if returning the string fails (which it will not), it will log the error.

If you want to throw an error, and catch it, you need to do it inside of the `try .. catch`

Here's an example

```
try {
  throw "This wll fail";
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in order to make it work as similar as you want you need to wrap your `ifs` with the `try`

```js
function isPositive(a) {
  try {
    if (a < 0) {
      throw 'Negative Number';
    }

    if (a == 0) {
      throw 'Codename Error Zero'
    }


    return 'It IS a positive number!';
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("we got an error");
    console.log(e);
  }

}

isPositive(0);
```

remember that a throw will stop the execution of the code that is after that throw, as an example:

as you can see, the code will stop in the first throw and the code after won't be executed, that is what is happening when you throw before your `try`

```js
function test() {
  throw 'we throw ASAP'
  var x = 1;
  var y = 2;

  throw 'another error';
  throw x + y;

  return x + y;
}

test()
```

also remember that the control of the `throw` will be passed to the first catch block in the call stack. so when you put `throw` outside the `try/catch` your error was being handled by another `try/catch`

something to get familiar with `throw` could be this article:
[Throw - javascript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw)

Comment: I did what you said at first, with the IFs and THROWs in the try block, I just tried again since you mentioned it and it still doesn't return anything for numbers which are actually positive. It just works for the error cases. so isPositive(0) and isPositive(-50) work fine but not isPositive(55) for example (which doesn't return anything).